# Fatal runtime error at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>

Tags: java, android, audio, runtime

I am working on equalier app and no errors in code at all. when I run app on phone it force closes, I logcat and this is result

```
 03-22 02:49:17.945: E/AndroidRuntime(4318):    at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>(Equalizer.java:149)
 03-22 02:50:34.796: E/AndroidRuntime(4423):    at android.media.audiofx.Equalizer.<init>(Equalizer.java:149)
```

I tried on android gingerbread `kitkat` and `jellybean`

this is the main activity code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener,
      CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
      View.OnClickListener
{

    //as usual "define variables"

    TextView bass_boost_label = null;
    SeekBar bass_boost = null;
    CheckBox enabled = null;
    Button flat = null;
    Button Button1;
    Equalizer eq = null; 
    BassBoost bb = null;

    int min_level = 0;
    int max_level = 100;

    static final int MAX_SLIDERS = 8; // Must match the XML layout
    SeekBar sliders[] = new SeekBar[MAX_SLIDERS];
    TextView slider_labels[] = new TextView[MAX_SLIDERS];
    int num_sliders = 0;

/*=============================================================================
    onCreate 
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
    }


/*=============================================================================
    onCreate 
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //initalize layout
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize the checkbox
        enabled = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.enabled);
        enabled.setOnCheckedChangeListener (this);

        //initialize flat button
        flat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flat);
        flat.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //the seekbars 
        bass_boost = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.bass_boost);
        bass_boost.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        bass_boost_label = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.bass_boost_label);

        sliders[0] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_1);
        slider_labels[0] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_1);
        sliders[1] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_2);
        slider_labels[1] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_2);
        sliders[2] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_3);
        slider_labels[2] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_3);
        sliders[3] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_4);
        slider_labels[3] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_4);
        sliders[4] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_5);
        slider_labels[4] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_5);
        sliders[5] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_6);
        slider_labels[5] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_6);
        sliders[6] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_7);
        slider_labels[6] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_7);
        sliders[7] = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.slider_8);
        slider_labels[7] = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.slider_label_8);


        //define equilizer
        eq = new Equalizer (0, 0);
        if (eq != null)
          {
          eq.setEnabled (true);
          int num_bands = eq.getNumberOfBands();
          num_sliders = num_bands;
          short r[] = eq.getBandLevelRange();
          min_level = r[0];
          max_level = r[1];

          for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders && i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
            {
            int[] freq_range = eq.getBandFreqRange((short)i);
            sliders[i].setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
            slider_labels[i].setText (formatBandLabel (freq_range));
            }
          }
        for (int i = num_sliders ; i < MAX_SLIDERS; i++)
          {
          sliders[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
          slider_labels[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

        bb = new BassBoost (0, 0);
        if (bb != null)
          {
          }
        else
          {
          bass_boost.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          bass_boost_label.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }

    updateUI();
    }

/*=============================================================================
    onProgressChanged
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged (SeekBar seekBar, int level, 
      boolean fromTouch) 
    {
        if (seekBar == bass_boost)
          {
          bb.setEnabled (level > 0 ? true : false); 
          bb.setStrength ((short)level); // Already in the right range 0-1000
          }
        else if (eq != null)
          {
          int new_level = min_level + (max_level - min_level) * level / 100; 

          for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders; i++)
            {
            if (sliders[i] == seekBar)
              {
              eq.setBandLevel ((short)i, (short)new_level);
              break;
              }
            }
          }
    }

/*=============================================================================
    onStartTrackingTouch
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    {
    }

/*=============================================================================
    onStopTrackingTouch
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) 
    {
    }

/*=============================================================================
    formatBandLabel 
=============================================================================*/
    public String formatBandLabel (int[] band) 
    {
    return milliHzToString(band[0]) + "-" + milliHzToString(band[1]);
    }

/*=============================================================================
    milliHzToString 
=============================================================================*/
    public String milliHzToString (int milliHz) 
    {
    if (milliHz < 1000) return "";
    if (milliHz < 1000000)
      return "" + (milliHz / 1000) + "Hz";
    else
      return "" + (milliHz / 1000000) + "kHz";
    }

/*=============================================================================
    updateSliders 
=============================================================================*/
    public void updateSliders ()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders; i++)
        {
        int level;
        if (eq != null)
          level = eq.getBandLevel ((short)i);
        else
          level = 0;
        int pos = 100 * level / (max_level - min_level) + 50;
        sliders[i].setProgress (pos);
        }
    } 

/*=============================================================================
    updateBassBoost
=============================================================================*/
    public void updateBassBoost ()
    {
    if (bb != null)
     bass_boost.setProgress (bb.getRoundedStrength());
    else
     bass_boost.setProgress (0);
    } 

/*=============================================================================
    onCheckedChange
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked)
    {
      if (view == (View) enabled)
        {
        eq.setEnabled (isChecked);
        }
    }

/*=============================================================================
    onClick
=============================================================================*/
    @Override
    public void onClick (View view)
    {
      if (view == (View) flat)
        {
        setFlat();
        }

      if (view == (View) Button1)
      {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Guide.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
      }
    }

/*=============================================================================
    updateUI
=============================================================================*/
    public void updateUI ()
      {
      updateSliders();
      updateBassBoost();
      enabled.setChecked (eq.getEnabled());
      }

/*=============================================================================
    setFlat 
=============================================================================*/
    public void setFlat ()
      {
      if (eq != null)
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_sliders; i++)
          {
          eq.setBandLevel ((short)i, (short)0);
          }
        }

      if (bb != null)
        {
        bb.setEnabled (false); 
        bb.setStrength ((short)0); 
        }

      updateUI();
      }

/*=============================================================================
    showAbout 
=============================================================================*/
    public void showAbout ()
      {
      AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

      alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("About Simple EQ");
      alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.copyright_message);
      alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
      alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton (R.string.ok, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
          { 
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
            }
          });
      AlertDialog ad = alertDialogBuilder.create();
      ad.show();

      }

/*=============================================================================
    onOptionsItemSelected 
=============================================================================*/
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
       switch (item.getItemId()) 
         {
         case R.id.about: 
           showAbout();
           return true;
         }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code?

Comment: That doesn't look like the entire exception trace. You should add the entire trace to your question.